# Seems like my SD Card just died... can I insert a new one?

Tags: htc-desire, external-sd, boot

So today my HTC Desire randomly froze, then started acting strangely - only showed the background image, nothing else. Didn't respond to power-off or anything so I pulled the battery.

After this, it simply would not boot up, just gets stuck on the boot up screen.

The phone is flashed with InsertCoin ROM so I can still get into fastboot but can't make backups - it can't load the SD Card. Error given is: **E:Can't Mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 (Invalid Argument)**

When I try to mount the SD Card to my computer it fails (ie. computer doesn't recognise it at all). Tried other random SD Cards and they mount no problem (thus shouldn't be a problem with the reader)

Main question... can I insert the original SD Card that came with the phone, and will the phone bootup and be usable? (note: this SD Card would be pretty much 'as-is' since I used a diff SD Card pretty much from day 1)

Sub question... anyone with ideas on if I can salvage what is left of this original SD Card? (can't seem to get anything to recognise it at all...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't use the original card.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a lot of headache (the replacement SD card I got sent from where I originally purchased turned out to be a 2GB card rebranded to be 16GB!), I think I now understand everything a bit better.

This is my understanding of the situation:

**Flashed with Insertcoin ROM** (and possibly other ROMS)

The SD card needs to be partitioned in a particular way for the custom ROM to work (ie it requires an ext2/3/4 partition to boot up). So inserting a brand new unpartitioned SD card **would not** work. You will at least need to format the card accordingly. With the correctly formatted card, I would imagine you can then boot up the phone. Data on the SD card will obviously be lost, but data on the phone should be ok.

Note: When I put in the new SD card, I wiped all caches, phone memory etc and re-flashed the ROM, so I lost everything. Though having played around with it a bit more, I do think it would have been possible if I just partitioned the SD card and booted the phone up. *(Not tried, just an educated guess, and if it is true, it will hopefully mean you lose less data in the unfortunate event that your SD card retires)*

**Stock non-flashed phone**

My guess is that you will be able to insert a new card and things should work. Data on the card will obviously be lost.